# multithreaded one read one write time_t

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I'm writing a multithreaded application that have 2 threads.
One of the threads receives data from a queue and aggregates it and the other one send the aggregated data to a server.

I want to be able to know the last time that a data was received so I use:

```
time_t last_data = time(NULL)
```

to get the correct time on each event (I dont need it to be super accurate but I need it to be fast) and then the other send this value with the aggregated data.

My questions are:

1. Do I have to synchronize this even if this is not very important that I get the most recent update?
2. I tested it with `std::atomic<time_t>` and it seems to have some performance issues, is there any other faster way?
3. What would be the worst case that can happen if I will not synchronize the read/write?
4. Is there a faster way to get the current time then `time(NULL)` (don't have to be super accurate)?

---

*UPDATE*

Here is an explanation of my application workflow.

Application needs:
 1. Consume data from external sources using IPC (currently [nanomsg](http://nanomsg.org/)).
 2. Aggregate the data to bulks.
 3. Send the aggregated data to remote server every given interval (1 second).

Current implementation:

1. Create 2 buffers to hold the aggregated data (one for receiving and one for sending).
2. Create a consumer thread to consume data from IPC and fill the receiving buffer.
3. Create a sending thread that will send the data to the server.
4. Every iteration of the interval the sending thread will swap the buffers (swap pointers and locking using mutex) and send the data to the server.

I don't want that the consumer will wait on network IO so I have created this flow.
Can I use event driven here instead of this complex mechanism without all the locking (currently it is working fine but i'm sure it can be better)?

Comment: Why are you doing it multi-threaded?

Comment: because I don't want to block the consuming from the queue while sending to the server

Comment: That is what I thought, see answer below.

Comment: questions 1 and 3 are unanswerable: see word “this” in question 1. What is “this”? Looks like you are trying to synchronise the two threads, is this correct. If so then it is not a good idea to use threads. Threads should be **mostly** independent, with little synchronisation. If they are spending a lot of time blocked/synchronising, then this is a sign that they should be a single thread.

Comment: Why do you use the library function from C instead of C++. What about `std::chrono::steady_clock::now()`?

Comment: @knivil from a small benchmark that I did, `time(NULL)` was the fastest

Answer (score 0):

Don't do it that way. You only need one thread. You can use select/poll/epoll. These can wait on your inputs, and at the same time for you output to finish. You will be doing event driven programming, and non-blocking output. It is something worth learning. It is a bit harder at first, but soon makes life easier i.e. not having the problem that you have now. Also the program will be faster.

Comment: This is recommendation, and not the actual answer.

Comment: This is the answer to the underlying question, how do I get my program to do what I want. The question is an XY problem. I am trying to do Y, I think I should do that by doing X. I can't do X, so I ask how to do X. I answered how to do Y.

Comment: Your thinking is based on assumptions. OP didn't provided enough information about architecture.

Comment: @AndrejsCainikovs that is true, I have assumed that they are using Unix (UNIX, BSD, MacOs, Gnu). They could be running some embedded system (though a lot of these allow event driven). Microsoft's Windows does not (as far as I know) allow this in C++ (but does allow it in C#). However Microsoft does not have a C++11 compiler.

Answer (score 0):

Supposing one thread executes:

```
last_data = time(NULL);
```

And the other uses `last_data` but there is no synchronization event between the two then there are no guarantees when or if the revised value of `last_data` will become visible to the reading thread.

However the most serious possibility is that write of `time_t` (maybe `long`) isn't atomic and another thread could read a corrupt 'part written' value.
That could cause glitches in delay and time calculations that might foul downstream process.

You might analyse your program and find that because the two interact there is a sufficient memory fence at some point that guarantees eventual update.

NB: This is an odd situation where I'm suspecting you think something isn't synchronized but it is! The usual experience is the other way around...

Basically there's not really enough information to understand what problem you're having.
For example, if the reader thread is the only process to read the time I'd expect to see code like:

Thread 1:
  If data received, lock L, update time, add to queue, unlock L.
Thread 2:
  If items in queue L, read queue and update time, unlock L .. process item.

In which case the time will be synchronized already.

Please provide a minimum, complete, verifiable example...